# Inserting JSON into MySQL using Python

Tags: python, mysql, json, python-db-api

I have a JSON object in Python.  I am Using Python DB-API and SimpleJson. I am trying to insert the json into a MySQL table.

At moment am getting errors and I believe it is due to the single quotes '' in the JSON Objects.

How can I insert my JSON Object into MySQL using Python?

Here is the error message I get:

```
error: uncaptured python exception, closing channel 
<twitstream.twitasync.TwitterStreamPOST connected at 
0x7ff68f91d7e8> (<class '_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError'>:
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the 
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for 
the right syntax to use near ''favorited': '0', 
'in_reply_to_user_id': '52063869', 'contributors': 
'NULL', 'tr' at line 1") 
[/usr/lib/python2.5/asyncore.py|read|68] 
[/usr/lib/python2.5/asyncore.py|handle_read_event|390] 
[/usr/lib/python2.5/asynchat.py|handle_read|137] 
[/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/twitstream-0.1-py2.5.egg/
twitstream/twitasync.py|found_terminator|55] [twitter.py|callback|26] 
[build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py|execute|166] 
[build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py|defaulterrorhandler|35])
```

Another error for reference

```
error: uncaptured python exception, closing channel 
<twitstream.twitasync.TwitterStreamPOST connected at 
0x7feb9d52b7e8> (<class '_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError'>:
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near 'RT @tweetmeme The Best BlackBerry Pearl 
Cell Phone Covers http://bit.ly/9WtwUO''' at line 1") 
[/usr/lib/python2.5/asyncore.py|read|68] 
[/usr/lib/python2.5/asyncore.py|handle_read_event|390] 
[/usr/lib/python2.5/asynchat.py|handle_read|137] 
[/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/twitstream-0.1-
py2.5.egg/twitstream/twitasync.py|found_terminator|55] 
[twitter.py|callback|28] [build/bdist.linux-
x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py|execute|166] [build/bdist.linux-
x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py|defaulterrorhandler|35])
```

Here is a link to the code that I am using http://pastebin.com/q5QSfYLa

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

try:
        import json as simplejson
except ImportError:
        import simplejson

import twitstream
import MySQLdb

USER = ''
PASS = ''

USAGE = """%prog"""


conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = "",
                       user = "",
                       passwd = "",
                       db = "")

# Define a function/callable to be called on every status:
def callback(status):

    twitdb = conn.cursor ()
    twitdb.execute ("INSERT INTO tweets_unprocessed (text, created_at, twitter_id, user_id, user_screen_name, json) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(status.get('text'), status.get('created_at'), status.get('id'), status.get('user', {}).get('id'), status.get('user', {}).get('screen_name'), status))

   # print status
     #print "%s:\t%s\n" % (status.get('user', {}).get('screen_name'), status.get('text'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Call a specific API method from the twitstream module:
    # stream = twitstream.spritzer(USER, PASS, callback)

    twitstream.parser.usage = USAGE
    (options, args) = twitstream.parser.parse_args()

    if len(args) < 1:
        args = ['Blackberry']

    stream = twitstream.track(USER, PASS, callback, args, options.debug, engine=options.engine)

    # Loop forever on the streaming call:
    stream.run()
```

Comment: A copy of the error message would be helpful :)

Comment: What code are you using to actually insert the JSON data into the database?

Comment: Hopefully a dumb question, but are you (hopefully) using bind variables?

Comment: @Gerrat sorry am a novice at Python and not sure if I know what a bind variable is :-( Sorry... Will put code online to show script.

Comment: @Will McCutchen I have added a copy of my code with the pastebin link...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

use json.dumps(json_value) to convert your json object(python object) in a json string that you can insert in a text field in mysql

http://docs.python.org/library/json.html

Comment: `str(json.dumps(json_value))` worked for me when data type of column is `text`. Without `str()` there was no error but the column was empty

Answer (score 8):

The most straightforward way to insert a python map into a MySQL JSON field...

```
python_map = { "foo": "bar", [ "baz", "biz" ] }

sql = "INSERT INTO your_table (json_column_name) VALUES (%s)"
cursor.execute( sql, (json.dumps(python_map),) )
```

Comment: many thanks this worked great when updating a row via a custom command-line interface by wrapping the nested json object with json.dumps

Answer (score 6):

To expand on the other answers:

Basically you need make sure of two things:

1. That you have room for the full amount of data that you want to insert in the field that you are trying to place it.  Different database field types can fit different amounts of data.
   See: [MySQL String Datatypes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-types.html). You probably want the "TEXT" or "BLOB" types.
2. That you are safely passing the data to database.  Some ways of passing data can cause the database to "look" at the data and it will get confused if the data looks like SQL. It's also a security risk. See: [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

The solution for #1 is to check that the database is designed with correct field type.

The solution for #2 is use parameterized (bound) queries. For instance, instead of:

```
# Simple, but naive, method.
# Notice that you are passing in 1 large argument to db.execute()
db.execute("INSERT INTO json_col VALUES (" + json_value + ")")
```

Better, use:

```
# Correct method. Uses parameter/bind variables.
# Notice that you are passing in 2 arguments to db.execute()
db.execute("INSERT INTO json_col VALUES %s", json_value)
```

Hope this helps. If so, let me know.  **:-)**

If you are still having a problem, then we will need to examine your syntax more closely.

Comment: @Aran Did my answer help?  If so vote up and mark answered.. thanks. :)

Comment: I have just uploaded my code and still seem to be getting errors am trying various ways to write the SQL query...

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to insert intyo a text or blob column easily

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO json_col VALUES %s", json_value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a look at the actual SQL string, try something like this:

```
sqlstr = "INSERT INTO tweets_unprocessed (text, created_at, twitter_id, user_id, user_screen_name, json) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", (status.get('text'), status.get('created_at'), status.get('id'), status.get('user', {}).get('id'), status.get('user', {}).get('screen_name'), status)
print "about to execute(%s)" % sqlstr
twitdb.execute(sqlstr)
```

I imagine you are going to find some stray quotes, brackets or parenthesis in there.

Comment: Ok if I have stray quotes, brackets or parenthesis - how can I prepare the string for use with SQL is there a function in Python DB-API?

Comment: For an error in the SQL syntax, "preparing the string for use with SQL" would mean fixing the syntax... probably not an API call for that :)

Post the output from the "about to execute..." statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
@route('/shoes', method='POST')
def createorder():
    cursor = db.cursor()
    data = request.json
    p_id = request.json['product_id']
    p_desc = request.json['product_desc']
    color = request.json['color']
    price = request.json['price']
    p_name = request.json['product_name']
    q = request.json['quantity']
    createDate = datetime.now().isoformat()
    print (createDate)
    response.content_type = 'application/json'
    print(data)
    if not data:
        abort(400, 'No data received')

    sql = "insert into productshoes (product_id, product_desc, color, price, product_name,         quantity, createDate) values ('%s', '%s','%s','%d','%s','%d', '%s')" %(p_id, p_desc, color, price, p_name, q, createDate)
    print (sql)
    try:
    # Execute dml and commit changes
        cursor.execute(sql,data)
        db.commit()
        cursor.close()        
    except:
    # Rollback changes
        db.rollback()
    return dumps(("OK"),default=json_util.default)
```

Answer (score 1):

One example, how add a `JSON` file into `MySQL` using `Python`. This means that it is necessary to convert the `JSON` file to `sql insert`, if there are several `JSON` objects then it is better to have only one call `INSERT` than multiple calls, ie for each object to call the function `INSERT INTO`.

```py
# import Python's JSON lib
import json

# use JSON loads to create a list of records
test_json = json.loads('''
[
    {
    "COL_ID": "id1",
    "COL_INT_VAULE": 7,
    "COL_BOOL_VALUE": true,
    "COL_FLOAT_VALUE": 3.14159,
    "COL_STRING_VAULE": "stackoverflow answer"
    },
    {
    "COL_ID": "id2",
    "COL_INT_VAULE": 10,
    "COL_BOOL_VALUE": false,
    "COL_FLOAT_VALUE": 2.71828,
    "COL_STRING_VAULE": "http://stackoverflow.com/"
    },
    {
    "COL_ID": "id3",
    "COL_INT_VAULE": 2020,
    "COL_BOOL_VALUE": true,
    "COL_FLOAT_VALUE": 1.41421,
    "COL_STRING_VAULE": "GIRL: Do you drink? PROGRAMMER: No. GIRL: Have Girlfriend? PROGRAMMER: No. GIRL: Then how do you enjoy life? PROGRAMMER: I am Programmer"
    }
]
''')

# create a nested list of the records' values
values = [list(x.values()) for x in test_json]
# print(values)

# get the column names
columns = [list(x.keys()) for x in test_json][0]

# value string for the SQL string
values_str = ""

# enumerate over the records' values
for i, record in enumerate(values):

    # declare empty list for values
    val_list = []
   
    # append each value to a new list of values
    for v, val in enumerate(record):
        if type(val) == str:
            val = "'{}'".format(val.replace("'", "''"))
        val_list += [ str(val) ]

    # put parenthesis around each record string
    values_str += "(" + ', '.join( val_list ) + "),\n"

# remove the last comma and end SQL with a semicolon
values_str = values_str[:-2] + ";"

# concatenate the SQL string
table_name = "json_data"
sql_string = "INSERT INTO %s (%s)\nVALUES\n%s" % (
    table_name,
    ', '.join(columns),
    values_str
)

print("\nSQL string:\n\n")
print(sql_string)
```

output:

```sh
SQL string:


INSERT INTO json_data (COL_ID, COL_INT_VAULE, COL_BOOL_VALUE, COL_FLOAT_VALUE, COL_STRING_VAULE)
VALUES
('id1', 7, True, 3.14159, 'stackoverflow answer'),
('id2', 10, False, 2.71828, 'http://stackoverflow.com/'),
('id3', 2020, True, 1.41421, 'GIRL: Do you drink? PROGRAMMER: No. GIRL: Have Girlfriend? PROGRAMMER: No. GIRL: Then how do you enjoy life? PROGRAMMER: I am Programmer.');
```

Answer (score 0):

The error may be due to an overflow of the size of the field in which you try to insert your json. Without any code, it is hard to help you.

Have you considerate a no-sql database system such as couchdb, which is a document oriented database relying on json format?

Comment: Both errors shown by OP contain: "You have an error in your SQL syntax;...".  This has nothing to do with an overflow of the size of the field.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick tip, if you want to write some inline code, say for a small json value, without `import json`. 
You can escape quotes in SQL by a double quoting, i.e. use `''` or `""`, to enter `'` or `"`.

Sample Python code (not tested):

```
q = 'INSERT INTO `table`(`db_col`) VALUES ("{k:""some data"";}")'
db_connector.execute(q)
```