# How can i add a json file in mysql database's table?

Tags: python, mysql, json

i want to save the data of json file in a table of mysql database. which i can access by python program. json File is like python dictionary with key and value. so database's table can have two columns. Json file is too long i can't entry the values in table by just typing. if someone know a method to import json file in database table please help.....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inserting JSON into MySQL using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251124/inserting-json-into-mysql-using-python)

Comment: @Digvijay S no it's not clear.